# numpy: select multiple arithmetic sequence elements to form multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose we get an array using following code, what is the efficient way to get `array[0], array[N], ..., array[MN-N]` to form a new array, and get `array[1], array[N+1],..., array[MN-N+1]` to form another array, and ..., etc.

```
array = []
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        array.append(something)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `numpy`, you can use `reshape`:

```
np.reshape(array, (M, N))
```

Then the columns are the arrays you are looking for.

---

```
M = 3
N = 2
​
array = []
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        array.append(i+j)

array
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

np.reshape(array, (M, N))
# array([[0, 1],
#        [1, 2],
#        [2, 3]])
```

Comment: What if in `for j in range(N)` loop, each time there generates an array instead of a scalar?

Comment: If that is the case, what should `array[0], array[N]` be then? Should it be 1d array or 2d array? You might consider `np.reshape(array, (M,N,length of the returned array in the for loop))`.

Comment: In this case, `array[0],...,array[MN-1]` are all 1d array, with shape like `(K,)`.

Comment: Why I need to consider `np.reshape(array, (M,N,length of the returned array in the for loop))`, can we just treat each array generated in the for loop as a `scalar`?